# discord.py Trying to store time in a db and check if 12 hours passed

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to check when 12 hours has passed since a user has voted and when I try to run the function through a `while True` loop, It doesn't run my bot.

```py
def check_votes():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    voted_users = votedb.votes.find({"voted": "true"})
    for user in voted_users:
        vote_time = user.get("vote_time")
        elapsed_time = now - vote_time
        if elapsed_time > datetime.timedelta(hours=12):
            votedb.votes.update_one({"user_id": user.get("user_id")}, {"$set": {"voted": "false"}})
            
while not client.is_closed():            
    while True:
        check_votes()
        time.sleep(3600)
```

This is making my bot not run and I'm trying to make it check when if it's been 12 hours since the `vote_time` which is set as `"vote_time": datetime.datetime.now()`

Comment: Maybe client.is_closed() is the problem? I tried your code with dummy values and without that client.is_closed (because I don't have that code) and it worked.

Comment: It does the same thing if I do `while True` instead